# Why SVC model returns prediction with array of values all equal to 1?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I have a database that represents different type of cousins for restaurants. For this database I already made a one hot encoding and it resulted in a series of columns with binary values as showed below (not all columns are showed).

[image]

I have to build a predictive model in order to predict y "%equal_class" value (from 1 to 10) given all cousin_type.
I tried using SVC model with below code

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=4)
from sklearn import svm
clf=svm.SVC(kernel='sigmoid',gamma='auto')
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
yhat=clf.predict(X_test)
```

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Predicted yhat value returns an array in which all values are equal to 1. I tried with different kernels but the result was the same.
Could you please tell me were I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the [data set is skewed/unbalanced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) (many samples with label 1 compared to other labels). You should perform a grid search and optimize the hyperparameters (in your case gamma) with respect to F1 score instead of setting it to "auto".